# SQL Between and Min and Max Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 2 tables table one is size and table 2 is products.

Problem is I've tried so many different query types but just can't seem to get it to work.

So size table has this content:

```
Dress_size
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Then product is similar to this:

product_name: White Dress

Min_Size: 3

Max_Size: 8

So I have a drop down of the dress_size, what I want to do is if the user seects e.g. 4 it displays white dress as it is between that, but if size 10 is selected it doesn't show due to it being bigger than 8.

I've tried a few here is what I've tried:

```
Select dress_size from size where (select Min(Min_Size) and Max(Max_Size) from product);

Select dress_size from size where dress_size between (Select Min_Size, Max_Size from product);
```

I know I need a where clause after product but just can't figure out what it needs to be.

Would I not need to reference dress_size table as how would the product table know what the min n max size is? N thanks for help.

I guess i didnt make this clear but dress_size n product info with min n max size n different tables which is why i have the nested select statements.

And yes the user does select a size which are the sizes in the size table diaplayed from dress_size column.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't the result just decide by what the user selects ?

```
SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE :user_select BETWEEN Min_Size AND Max_Size
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_name from product where SELECTED_SIZE<=max_size and
     SELECTED_SIZE>=min_size;
```

replace SELECTED_SIZE with your selected size number

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dress_size from size where dress_size >= minsize and maxsize <=dress_size
```

alternatively

```
Select dress_size from size where dress_size between minsize and maxsize
```